# Minimum of function forming a manifold

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, smooth-manifolds

Usually, everybody talks about minimum points of a function in the singular. But what if the minimum of a function forms an entire manifold? My example comes from this simple minimization
$$ \min_{x,y} U(x, y) = \tfrac{1}{2} \left( \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} - r \right)^2 $$
Clearly, all points on a circle of radius $r$ satisfy the minimum criterion, i.e., $\nabla U(x, y) = (0 \, 0)^T$. This means we can use implicit equation to describe this manifold, e.g.,  $\phi(x, y) = x^2 + y^2 - r^2 = 0$. But we knew this by construction.

What about in general? Given a function $U(\mathbf x)$ of many variables $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, how can we know if the minimum points are forming a circle, a torus or any manifold embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$? And moreover, how can you find the function $\phi(\mathbf{x})$ such that $\phi(\mathbf{x}^*)=0$ when $\mathbf{x}^*$ is a minimum of $U$?

Update: What I did find to work is $U(\mathbf{x}) = \lVert \phi(\mathbf{x}) \rVert^2/2$ such that $\nabla U(\mathbf{x})=\nabla \phi(\mathbf{x})^T \phi(\mathbf{x})$. Or pretty much any function of $\phi$ that is zero/minimum for $\phi = 0$. But how do you go in reverse, when you don't know $\phi$? This is my problem. And what conditions does $U$ need to satisfy such that $\phi(\mathbf{x})$ is not a naive single minimum point, i.e., $\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}^*=0$.

Comment: It is not completely satisfactory, but obvious candidate is $\phi(\textbf{x}) = \nabla U (\textbf{x})$ or if you like scalar functions $\phi(\textbf{x}) = ||\nabla U (\textbf{x})||^2$

Comment: It doesn't work as we should have $\phi : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. The second one might work, but I'm not convinced.

Comment: This gives you all critical points of $\phi$. So you've got union of local maxima, local minima and saddle points.

Comment: Yes, you're right and it's pretty good answer, thanks! I feel that my curiosity is still not satisfied though. I would like to be able to express $U(\phi(\mathbf{x}))$ or to know more about what type of surface $\phi$ describes (I guess it can also be $\phi: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m, m <n$).